# Proving that product of two-point sets is compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am reading Jech's Axiom of Choice, and I want to prove:

> For a non-empty set $I$, if $\{0,1\}^I$, the generalized Cantor space, is non-empty compact, then $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ where $|A_i|=2$ for all $i\in I$ is non-empty compact where the topologies on both $\{0,1\}$ and $A_i$'s are discrete.

Jech notes that it suffices to show that $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ is non-empty, and I am wondering if the below argument works formally. (argument for why proving that $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ is non-empty is sufficient).

My idea right now is: once we know $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ is non-empty, let $f\in \prod_{i\in I} A_i$. For each $i\in I$, we may identify $f(i)$ with $0$. So can we create a map $F:\{0,1\}^I\to \prod_{i\in I} A_i$ by: given $\alpha\in \{0,1\}^I$, $F$ sends $\alpha$ to $f_\alpha$ where $f_\alpha(i)=f(i)$ if $\alpha(i)=0$ and otherwise, take $f_\alpha(i)$ be the unique element of the set $A_i\setminus \{f(i)\}$. If we can create the such map $F$, then $F$ will give an isomorphism.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Holy moly......

Comment: Excuse me but I know Tychonoff's theorem is equivalent to AC.  This seems reminiscent to that.   But I never yet got a handle on why that is (there's a story there, but I'll spare you).

Comment: Notice that the statement can be false if the Axiom of Choice doesn't hold.  That means you need to use at least some version of the Axiom of Choice in your proof.  Where are you doing so?  (Hint:  How can you "identify $f(i)$ with $0$"?  How do you know there is a function $f \in \prod A_i$?)

Comment: Sorry if my question is oddly phrased, but I was wondering how to prove that $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ is non-empty compact using two assumptions: 1. $\{0,1\}^I$ is non-empty compact, and 2. $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ is non-empty.

Comment: You need to explain why $F^{-1}$ is continuous, but the idea is correct. (Side note, even in ZF you don't need the assumptions that $\{0,1\}^I$ and $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ are non-empty to get compactness)

Comment: @ℋolo Could you  explain in a comment one doesn't need nonempty to show compactness?

Comment: @coffeemath $\{0,1\}^I$ is already provably nonempty. And if $\prod_i A_i$ were empty, it would be compact, so nonemptiness is an admissible assumption for proving compactness if that’s all you care about. (But it’s interesting to prove nonemptiness as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right idea for the step you’re asking about. Moreover, it shows that the assumption that the $A_i$‘s have the discrete topology is superfluous. Your $F$ is bijective, and it’s continuous regardless of the topologies of the $A_i$’s (why?). Thus, $\prod_i A_i$ is the continuous image of a compact set.

But I don’t think the result is quite correct how you’ve stated it, since I don’t think you can actually prove the nonemptiness of $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ from the compactness of $2^I.$ (Or at least I don’t know how and the claim isn’t implicit in what Jech actually wrote in the exercises you got this from.) What you can do is prove the nonemptiness and compactness of any product of sets of size 2 from the general statement that $2^J$ is compact for any set $J$.